# Removing trailing new line after printing on Mac OS X zsh

Tags: macos, shell, line, trailing

i'm trying to print stdin without the trailing new line that appears after using cat, grep, awk etc. (Mac OS X zsh)
Unfortunately, echo -n doesn't work, it prints some weird character.

Do you have any idea on the matter ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

From man zshoptions:

```
PROMPT_SP <D>
              Attempt  to  preserve  a  partial  line (i.e. a line that did not end
              with a newline) that would otherwise be covered up by the command prompt
              due to the PROMPT_CR option.  This works by outputting some
              cursor-control characters,
              including a series of spaces, that should make the terminal wrap to the
              next line when a partial line is present (note that this is only 
              successful if your terminal has automatic margins, which is typical).

              When a partial line is preserved, by default you will see an inverse+bold
              character at the end of the partial line:  a "%" for a normal user or a
              "#" for root.  If set, the shell parameter PROMPT_EOL_MARK can be used
              to customize how the end of partial lines are shown.

              NOTE: if the PROMPT_CR option is not set, enabling this option will have
              no effect.  This option is on by default.
```

Add this to your .zshrc to change the behavior. And note that this is a feature by design, not a bug.

`export PROMPT_EOL_MARK=''`